# How to set up login/guest and checkout/add to cart

Tags: database-design

I want to create an online store database. I want to give users the ability to 'add to cart' and 'check out' without login.

My idea is that if the user logs in, then I can save the information in tables `ex(bag, order)`, but if the user wants to check out as guest than I can create a `guest_unique_id` and set up `bag` that way. Guest bag will be mannually deleted after 10 days.

The only issue I see is that sometimes `account_id` will be empty. I guess I can check to see if `guest_unique_id` is `NULL` then user has an account, if not then it is a guest.
What you guys think about this structure, is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not have `account_id` always populated? When anyone who creates a shopping bag, they get an `account_id` auto assigned, but there's another field on the account table with a boolean `is_guest` flag set true by default. You could keep things like customer details in a separate table with a 1:1 map to the account table, for customers who do create accounts.

Your challenge then is that you might have repeat customers with different `account_id`s, but might be worth it depending on how likely customers will create accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to create a separate Bag table for guest users ex. (GUEST_BAG_TB), create a column in this table called guest_ip_address to store their ip address and use that to track them, then on checkout since you will be collecting their email generate a random password and email it to them and automatically register them through that, then block them the next time they try to check out as a guest with the same email and ask them to login. From time to time, run a cron job and delete old entries in the GUEST_BAG_TB table if necessary. The IS_Guest boolean column in the IS_ACCOUNT_TB table will not be necessary.

Answer (score -2):

what if every user will be guest at start until the user access sign-in. on successful sign-in. Then use your logic of user and guest. This is also an option.